# What's this stick-like thing on the glass of C-130J?

Tags: feature-identification, c-130, windscreen

Just was watching this video:

[C-130J Shadow Formation Landing](https://www.reddit.com/r/aviation/comments/mvfgiu/c130j_shadow_formation_landing_saw_another_post/)

You can see this stick-like thing on the glass of the aircraft.

[image]

What's it? a sensor?

Comment: It can be for window heating, but I am just guessing

Comment: Just watched the video. That's a bizarre camera angle - I thought he was crabbed against a massive crosswind, but it's actually the angle of the camera that makes it look that way. Either that, or there's a lot of curvature of glass on the nose of a Herc so that it just _appears_ that we're looking out the side.

Comment: @FreeMan, the camera is obviously looking through the side window (it is behind captain's left shoulder), a little to the left, and is tilted to the right so the horizon does not appear level. Looks like just shoddy camera placement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of the windshield anti-icing system, and is the same as on the Navy's C-130T. From the [NATOPS flight manual for the T model](https://info.publicintelligence.net/USNavy-C130T.pdf), page 2-150:

> The three windshields, the two windows on each side of the windshields, and the two lower windows in front of the pilot are NESA-type. These panels are heated by applying unregulated ac power from the left-hand ac bus to a resistance material between the layers of glass. The ac power is applied by automatic dc control systems that cycle to maintain window temperature within specific limits. A center windshield system controls heating of the three center windshields, and a side and lower system controls heating of the side and lower windows. The two systems are identical except for the amount of total ac power provided.